# React DOM not updated when prop from redux store changes

Tags: reactjs, dom, redux

This is driving me crazy for hours now... I have a module that displays a list that is fetched from a server and loaded into the redux store on button press. That works properly. I mention this as this is the reason why I don't understand the following behavior.

This object array from the store is mapped into my component with

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        extracted_templates: state.extracted_templates
    }
}
```

And used in the `render()` as follows... I removed some other DOM parts to keep it simple

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className="main-container">
            {Object.values(this.props.extracted_templates).length > 0 ?
                <ExtractedTemplatesList templates={Object.entries(this.props.extracted_templates)} clickHandler={this.clickHandler} /> : '' }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `clickHandler` modifies the store using the same action as the fetch function uses.

```
clickHandler(action, id, parent){
    console.log(action+" "+parent)
    switch(action){
        case 'dismiss':
            let new_template_list = this.props.extracted_templates
            delete new_template_list[id]
            // console.log(new_template_list)
            this.props.dispatch(setExtractedTemplates(new_template_list))
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Everything is called correctly, **the store updates** correctly (as I can see in my web-dev console) but this time the DOM doesn't get updated.
For completeness, here's the action and the reducer implementation

action:

```
export const setExtractedTemplates = (templates) => ({
    type: actions.SET_EXTRACTED_TEMPLATES,
    payload: templates
    });
```

reducer:

```
case actions.SET_EXTRACTED_TEMPLATES:
    console.log({action})
    return {
        ...state, 
        extracted_templates: action.payload
}
```

Comment: If you add a `console.log(state)` inside of `mapStateToProps` do you see the log/updated values? That will point the debugging process to redux or the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mutating the existing data, *and* you're putting the exact same object back into the store:

```js
let new_template_list = this.props.extracted_templates
delete new_template_list[id]
this.props.dispatch(setExtractedTemplates(new_template_list))
```

Both of those are bugs. You should never mutate data from the store, and the result of an action should be *new* data in the store.

This is one of the reasons why [we recommend putting as much logic as possible into reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers).  Also, you should be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which would both catch this accidental mutation here, and simplify the update logic in a reducer.

Comment: I thought because I do `let new_template_list = this.props.extracted_templates` I'm explicitly not mutating the store but seems like this assumption was wrong then...

Comment: Nope. That just creates another variable that points to the exact same object in memory.  See the Redux docs page on [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) and this post on [The Complete Guide to Immutability in React and Redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/) for explanations on how to do immutable updates properly. You might also want to look at [A Visual Guide to References in JS](https://daveceddia.com/javascript-references/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 clickHandler(action, id, parent){
        console.log(action+" "+parent)
        switch(action){
            case 'dismiss':
                let new_template_list = {...this.props.extracted_templates} //make a new copy
                delete new_template_list[id]
                // console.log(new_template_list)
                this.props.dispatch(setExtractedTemplates(new_template_list))
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }
    }
```

You modified the same object saved in the redux store. This is potentially dangerous because you changed the state without using a reducer. When React did the shallow comparison, it didn't see difference so UI was not updated. You can make a copy before save it to store.

Further more you can modify your reducer in this way:

```
case actions.SET_EXTRACTED_TEMPLATES:
    console.log({action})
    return {
        ...state, 
        extracted_templates: [...action.payload] //make a new copy
}
```